# Injecting dependencies into classes with a custom decorator in aurelia

Tags: aurelia

In aurelia, is it possible to have a custom decorator automatically inject dependencies into the classes it decorates or does each decorated class need to inject the dependencies itself (at least in its constructor)?

In other words, is this the best that can be done:

**Custom Decorator (my-decorator.js)**

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Dependency} from 'dependency';

export function MyDecorator() {
    return function(target) {
        inject(Dependency)(target);
    }
}
```

**Decorated Class**

```
import {MyDecorator} from "my-decorator";

@MyDecorator()
export class DecoratedClass {
    constructor(dependency) {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `inject` property of a class is typically static.  When most of the resolvers are used they simply "augment" the static inject property so that the container can resolve them using the specified resolver and pass them to the constructor.  I don't know that a class decorator would help in this instance as it doesn't decorate the instance in anyway that I can think of, though I may be wrong.

If you are trying to create a new instance and still use DI to resolve dependencies you should look at the `Factory` resolver which supports this.

If you are trying to completely leave the constructor alone another idea would be to decorate a property or function instead which uses a complete separate property `static customInject` for example that resolves dependencies on the instance when invoked at start.